# Angular registry for entry components

Tags: angular, dynamic, plugins, widget, dashboard

I need to device a component that shows a configurable dashboard of widgets.
The main application should provide a dashboard component that, based on a configuration, displays widgets in a grid.
For each widget, a widget container component is instantiated, which calls a service that returns a component type (ie a decorated class). The type is used to resolve its component factory and the latter is used to create the component inside a ViewComponentRef inside the widget container.

widget-container.html:

```
<div class="placeholder" #target></div>
<div class="loader">
    <mat-spinner [diameter]="50"></mat-spinner>
</div>
```

widget-container.ts:

```
constructor(
    private readonly _el: ElementRef,
    private readonly _renderer: Renderer2,
    private _componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private readonly _widgetService: WidgetService
) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    const componentClass = this._widgetService.getWidget(this.widgetDefinition.componentName);
    const factory = this._componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentClass);
    this._componentRef = this._viewContainer.createComponent(factory);
    const newItem: WidgetBase = this._componentRef.instance;
}
```

Now, the application needs to be extensible with modules that plug additional functionalities. Say that these modules are imported into the app as npm plugin packages:

main-app.module.ts:

```
import { Plugin1Module } from "@mycompany/plugin1";

[...]

@NgModule({
    imports: [..., Plugin1Module], [...]
})
export class MainAppModule {}
```

Therefore, since the Plugin1Module is AOT compiled by who developed it, my widget service cannot any longer return a Component Type given a string, what it now needs to return is a ComponentFactory. So it becomes a service that must be able to retrieve a list of all component factories loaded at that point, even from modules imported elsewhere, and find a specific one given some kind of identifier.
How can I achieve this? I'm trying to understand what to have injected in this service: which angular service provides a list of all existing component factories?

Answer (score 0):

Fiddling with the code, I've come to this hacky solution in my widget resolver service:

```
getWidgetComponentFactory(componentName: string): ComponentFactory<WidgetBase> {
    let ret: ComponentFactory<WidgetBase> = null;
    let found = false;
    (this._resolver as any)._factories.forEach((f: ComponentFactory<any>) => {
        if (found) {
            return;
        }

        if (f.componentType.name === `${componentName}Component`) {
            ret = f;
            found = true;
        }
    });
    return ret;
}
```

I know _factories is there on the ComponentFactoryResolver service, it just isn't exposed. The only public function takes a Type<{}> as an argument but I can't have the actual Component class, all I have is the name of the class, so I need to manually find the factory from the list of all factories known to angular.

Is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: Just to clarify, this solution does not work anymore since Angular 9. From what I can see there is still no easy way to create a component dynamically from a string without manually maintaining a string->Type map. See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24360 for a discussion about this topic.